# Why won't this query return results that are 0?

Tags: mysql, coordinates

Using haversine, the following query finds all rows that have coordinates within a 10 mile radius of the inputted coordinates.

```
SELECT *
     , ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($locationLatitude) ) 
                   * cos( radians( endingLatitude ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( endingLongitude ) - radians( $locationLongitude ) ) 
                   + sin( radians( $locationLatitude) ) 
                   * sin( radians( endingLatitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM trips 
HAVING distance < 10 
 ORDER 
    BY distance 
 LIMIT 0 , 10;
```

However, it does not return rows that have the same exact coordinates as the coordinates inputted. Why is this?

Comment: That sounds suspicious, like something is not working.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: I think could have a problem with the data type precision. Even if the longitude and latitude match, the "distance" may be not zero depending of the data type precision along the math functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using incorrect syntax: Change `HAVING` to `WHERE` and use a subquery so you can refer to the alias of the calculation rather than having to repeat the formula:

```
select * from (
    select *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($locationLatitude) ) 
               * cos( radians( endingLatitude ) ) 
               * cos( radians( endingLongitude ) - radians( $locationLongitude ) ) 
               + sin( radians( $locationLatitude) ) 
               * sin( radians( endingLatitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    from trips) x
WHERE distance < 10
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

`HAVING` is for conditions on aggregated values for groups, eg `GROUP BY FOO HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`, but you aren't doing any grouping; you need a simple where clause.

Unfortunately, mysql has "lenient" grouping syntax which has allowed your statement to execute without a syntax error, even though it is logically unsound. The same query run on other databases would cause an error.

Comment: Well, HAVING saves the OP writing out the whole formula twice. It might not be orthodox, but it's OK

Comment: @strawberry OP can use subquery to refer to column alias of calculation result. Neither WHERE nor HAVING can do this directly (without subquery)

Comment: @dummy i filled in the placeholder code - is that clearer? It should run as is

Comment: @Bohemian Code works, it just does not return anything where the coordinates are the exact same as the ones stored in the table.

Comment: @dummycode.com As the two points converge, the inner calculation tends to 1, and acos(1) = 0 so the overall result tends to 0 (as expected). There are no divide-by-zero possibilities. I can't see why there would be a problem. Can you please post a link to an [SQLFiddle](http://SQLFiddle.com) with some actual data you are using, including the data the "should work" but doesn't, and let me know when you've done that

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks a lot for your time and the help! Appreciate it.